# Error root routing on React

Tags: reactjs, routes, jsx

Uncaught Error: The root route must render a single element. I'am not understand when this happens. Show me please, what I don't understand?

menu.jsx:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Link } from 'react-router'

class Menu extends React.Component {
   render() {
      return (
         <div>
            <ul>
               <Link to="/">Home</Link>
               <Link to="/contacts">Contacts</Link>
               <Link to="/about">About</Link>
            </ul>               
           {this.props.children}
         </div>
      )
   }
}
```

about.jsx (and etc. components):

```
import React from 'react';

export default class About extends React.Component {
   render() {
      return (
         <div>
            <h1>About...</h1>
         </div>
      )
   }
}
```

appStart.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import Home from './app/templates/home';
import About from './app/templates/about';
import Contacts from './app/templates/contacts';

import Menu from './app/layouts/menu';

import { Route, Router, browserHistory, IndexRoute } from "react-router";

ReactDOM.render((
   <Router history = {browserHistory}>
      <Route path = "/" component = {Menu}>
         <IndexRoute component = {Home} />
         <Route path = "/home" component = {Home} />
         <Route path = "/about" component = {About} />
         <Route path = "/contacts" component = {Contacts} />
      </Route>
   </Router>

), app)
```

structure of project:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably it is because you forgot to `export` your component in `menu.jsx`.

```
export default class Menu extends React.Component {
    // ... rest of the code
```

Also as @mayank-shukla pointed out, you should find the node where you want to render your app in the DOM.

```
ReactDOM.render((
  <Router history = {browserHistory}>
    <Route path = "/" component = {Menu}>
       <IndexRoute component = {Home} />
       <Route path = "/home" component = {Home} />
       <Route path = "/about" component = {About} />
       <Route path = "/contacts" component = {Contacts} />
    </Route>
  </Router>
), document.getElementById("app"));
```

Assuming your `.html` file has something like this `<div id="app"></div>`

Comment: @free-soul, big thanx, so one, ), document.getElementById("app")); = ), app); - work, and export default.

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is in your `appStart` component, first get the html element by `document.getElementById()` then render the component inside that. Try this:

```
ReactDOM.render((
  <Router history = {browserHistory}>
    <Route path = "/" component = {Menu}>
       <IndexRoute component = {Home} />
       <Route path = "/home" component = {Home} />
       <Route path = "/about" component = {About} />
       <Route path = "/contacts" component = {Contacts} />
    </Route>
  </Router>
), document.getElementById("app"))
```

Define this id "app" and include the bundle file in your html page, like this:

```
<div id="app"/>
<script src = "bundle.js"/>
```